# Not able to save quote document as pdf display from the visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, quote, document, getcontentaspdf

I have one visualforce page called : QuoteDetail.

This page have button called : Generate PDF.

This Generate pdf open up a popup with selection (checkboxes) 1. Remove items with no quantity 2. Show Discount.

In my pdf i have some list of products with it's details, Now, when i set the checkboxes true before generating pdf then Product with 0 quantity can not display (which is my result in pdf) which is true and pdf will show up as expected with No product who have quantity is 0.

**Problem is :** I have button called - "Save PDF to Quote", When i click on this button the generated pdf will save in Quote as a quote document but it will save with those all product with quantity 0. expected output is i want save pdf in quote document as it generated. in short generated PDF does not have product with quantity 0(which is correct) and save PDF does have product with quantity 0(Which is incorrect).

**visualforce page : QuoteDetail**

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;">
    <table border="0" width="98%" cellpadding="7">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_removeitem" id="checkbox_removeitem" /> Remove items with no quantity
                <!--<apex:inputcheckbox value="{!Quote.Remove_items_with_no_quantity__c}" label="Remove items with no quantity" id="checkbox_removeitem"> 

                </apex:inputcheckbox> Remove items with no quantity-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_includediscount" id="checkbox_includediscount" /> Show Discount
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_removepricing" id="checkbox_removepricing" /> Remove Line Item Price
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_removeGrandTotalBox" id="checkbox_removeGrandTotalBox" /> Remove Grand Total Box
            </td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <apex:commandButton value="Preview PDF" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="tstpopup" onClick="javascript:OpenPDF('{!Quote.Id}');"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Apex class : with method of save document**

```
public PageReference attachwithquote() {

    PageReference thePDF =  Page.QuotePDF;
    thePDF.getParameters().put('id',(String)this.Quote.Id);
    thePDF.setRedirect(true);


    if(!test.isrunningtest()){
        quotedocument qd = new quotedocument();
        qd.document = thePDF.getContentAsPDF();
        qd.quoteId = this.Quote.Id;
        insert qd;
    }
    PageReference quotePage = new PageReference('/apex/QuoteDetail?id='+ this.Quote.Id);
    quotePage.setRedirect(true);
    return quotePage;
    //return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what is exactly the problem.

Comment: Apologize for that, let me update my question with more detailing

Comment: @MartinLezer, Please see updated question i've tried to explain bit more about my problem

Comment: @NailDavid can you remove thePDF.setRedirect(true); in your code and check again. It seems that it is not keeping the state of your variables.

Comment: @Kevan Nope, Not working

Comment: @NailDavid I guess you will need to pass the filter criteria via parameters like you did for id and on your controller for the pdf, you process them.

Comment: @Kevan yes, that make sense but variable i used for checkboxes are locally declared, how can i access them in class ? any idea

Comment: @MartinLezer Does it clear to understand ?